# how to cite this book with bibtex?

Tags: bibtex, citing, books

This might be an easy question to some of you but for me I find it hard because I am not familiar with the names mentioned. Which is a city and which is a publisher.

```
Mack, Chris A. Fundamental Principles of Optical Lithography - The Science of Microfabrication. Chichester, West Sussex, England ; Hoboken, NJ, USA: Wiley. Print.
```

Comment: wiley is the publisher.  there are two cities: chichester and hoboken.  hope this is enough to get you going.

Comment: http://explore.bl.uk/primo_library/libweb/action/display.do?frbrVersion=2&tabs=moreTab&ct=display&fn=search&doc=BLL01014459185&indx=1&recIds=BLL01014459185&recIdxs=0&elementId=0&renderMode=poppedOut&displayMode=full&frbrVersion=2&dscnt=2&fromLogin=true&tab=local_tab&dstmp=1423171332393&vl%28freeText0%29=The%20Science%20of%20Microfabrication&vid=BLVU1&mode=Basic

Comment: This looks off-topic to me: the link to TeX (or BibTeX) is tenuous at best.

Comment: https://verbosus.com/bibtex-style-examples.html is helpful for BibTeX examples, for future viewers (I came to this question while searching for something like this link).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Like this?

Bib File (same name as in `\addbibresource{}`):

```
@BOOK{principles,
  TITLE = {Fundamental Principles of Optical Lithography},
  SUBTITLE = {The Science of Microfabrication},
  AUTHOR = {Mack, Chris A},
  YEAR = {2007}, % I looked it up
  PUBLISHER = {Wiley},
}
```

LaTeX-Document:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{principles}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Compile with latex, biber, latex. e.g. pdflatex

Output:
[image]

Comment: How to add chapter?

Comment: Add `CHAPTER = {...}` to the fields in the bib file

Comment: `CHAPTER` isn't acceptable for `BOOK` according to this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BibTeX. So i change my type from `BOOK` to `INBOOK`.

Comment: This example does not use bibtex, but biblatex + biber.

Comment: See section 2.1.1 of the biblatex manual